# Conan - no bintray?

Tags: conan, bintray

I'm trying to add Conan support to my project.
Unfortunately I can't find the libraries:

- GLI
- PHYSFS

that were hosted on bintray.

I read that bintray has been shut down and repositories are being moved successively to conan center.
In this case I have a question how can I download these libraries using Conan?
Is there any way around this problem?

Conan PhysFs repository:
https://github.com/bincrafters/conan-physfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bincrafters repositories was migrated to Artifactory Cloud, you can use the address:

```
conan remote add bincrafters https://bincrafters.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/conan/public-conan
```

You can visualize Bincrafters' repository here: https://bincrafters.jfrog.io

Also, it's well documented [here](https://bincrafters.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using_packages.html#adding-the-bincrafters-repository-as-a-conan-remote) and [here](https://bincrafters.github.io/2020/04/19/infrastructure-changes-and-required-actions/)